# how to process form_with using GET request as XHR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 6 app, and want to update page view based on a dropdown value selected using XHR. Dropdown must use GET method coz I am calling index action.

I am using `form_with` which by default uses `remote: true`.
I am not using `local: true`.

I tried `onchange: "Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit')"` - this does send XHR request and receives a response but does not update view.

I tried `onchange: "this.form.submit();"` - this does a full page reload not utilizing XHR.

Code from app/views/users/index.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_with url: station_users_path(station_id: Current.user.home_station), method: :get do |form| %>
          <%= form.select :user_status, options_for_select( { "Active users" => "unlocked", "Inactive users" => "locked"}, @user_status ), {}, { :onchange => "Rails.fire(this.form, 'submit')" } %>
        <% end %>
```

Code from app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```rb
  def index
    @user_status = params[:user_status] || "unlocked"
    @users = @station.users.send(@user_status) || []
    @user_status == "unlocked" ? seperate_managers_from_users : @managers = []
  end
```

Comment: I think you should JS for the functionality you are looking for. Add a class like :class => "my_select_tag", then add  $(".my_select_tag").change(function() {  $.ajax({ ...add what you want... }) } ) for responding to the change in option. You should add a route which will return a JS file for changing the view.

Answer (score 0):

In onchange just write one `get_station_users()` function. Inside that you can use ajax calling.

**In forms**

```
<%= form_with url: station_users_path(station_id: Current.user.home_station), id: “form_id”, method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.select :user_status, options_for_select( { "Active users" => "unlocked", "Inactive users" => "locked"}, @user_status ), {}, { :onchange => "get_station_users()" } %>
<% end %>
```

**Add Script**

```
function get_station_users(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/station_users",
    data: {  $('#form_id').serialize(), },
    dataType: 'script'
});
}
```

Your response will be as `JS.` So you can use `index.js.erb`

Comment: **Getting error:** `Uncaught ReferenceError: get_station_users is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (users:152) onchange @ users:152`.

Is there any better solution? I might have other forms like this on project and adding a JS file every-time does not seems rails way.